Is there any possibility to prohibit delete for special items in SwipeToDismissBox?
I have a SwipeToDismissBox, here a sample from YouTube:
@file:OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)

package com.plcoding.swipetodeletecompose

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.animation.fadeOut
import androidx.compose.animation.shrinkVertically
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Delete
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.SwipeToDismissBox
import androidx.compose.material3.SwipeToDismissBoxState
import androidx.compose.material3.SwipeToDismissBoxValue
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.plcoding.swipetodeletecompose.ui.theme.SwipeToDeleteComposeTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SwipeToDeleteComposeTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
                ) {
                    val programmingLanguages = remember {
                        mutableStateListOf(
                            "Kotlin",
                            "Java",
                            "C++",
                            "C#",
                            "JavaScript",
                            "Python",
                            "Swift",
                            "Ruby",
                            "Go",
                            "Rust",
                        )
                    }

                    LazyColumn(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                    ) {
                        items(
                            items = programmingLanguages,
                            key = { it },
                        ) { language ->
                            SwipeToDeleteContainer(
                                item = language,
                                onDelete = {
                                    programmingLanguages -= language
                                },
                            ) { language ->
                                Text(
                                    text = language,
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                                        .padding(16.dp),
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> SwipeToDeleteContainer(
    item: T,
    onDelete: (T) -> Unit,
    animationDuration: Int = 500,
    content: @Composable (T) -> Unit,
) {
    var isRemoved by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val state = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState(
        confirmValueChange = { value ->
            if (value == SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart) {
                isRemoved = true
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        },
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = isRemoved) {
        if (isRemoved) {
            delay(animationDuration.toLong())
            onDelete(item)
        }
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = !isRemoved,
        exit = shrinkVertically(
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationDuration),
            shrinkTowards = Alignment.Top,
        ) + fadeOut(),
    ) {
        SwipeToDismissBox(
            state = state,
            backgroundContent = {
                DeleteBackground(swipeDismissState = state)
            },
        ) {
            content(item)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DeleteBackground(
    swipeDismissState: SwipeToDismissBoxState,
) {
    val color = if (swipeDismissState.dismissDirection == SwipeToDismissBoxValue.EndToStart) {
        Color.Red
    } else Color.Transparent

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(color)
            .padding(16.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterEnd,
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.White,
        )
    }
}

Is there any possibility to prohibit deletion of special items, here for example, programmingLanguage == Kotlin?
I tried to do this in the onDelete method, but this fails, because swiping is not disabled. So I am looking for a hook, where I can disable the swing for certain strings.

The swipes in the SwipeToDismissBox can be disabled like this:
SwipeToDismissBox(
    // ...
    enableDismissFromStartToEnd = false,
    enableDismissFromEndToStart = false,
) {
    content(item)
}

